# Django: get_absolute_url not working

Tags: python, django

In Django, I want to display a detailed view of model objects by using the get_absolute_url method as described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url).

The URL structure for each detail is something like this...

```
url.com/company/(?P< company_id >[0-9]+)/people/(?P< slug >[0-9]+)/$
```

where .../people/ is the list view and the .../people/slug/ is the detail for each object

Which returns the NoReverseMatch error like so

> NoReverseMatch at /company/google/people/

as I put the `href='{{ people.get_absolute_url }}'` in my template.

Does anybody know if using the 'company_id' kwarg in the URL is causing problems rendering the page with the get_absolute_url href for the 'slug' kwarg?

I've done this many times before with a hardcoded URL before the kwarg variable which worked; such as 'company/people/(?P< slug >[0-9]+)/$' - note there's only one keyword

Full Error:

> Reverse for 'people-detail' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments
>   '{u'slug': u'798224891221678'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried:
>   ['company/(?P< company_id >[0-9]+)/people/(?P< slug >[0-9]+)/$']

get_absolute_url method:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('people-detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
```

Comment: Please show your models and `get_absolute_url` method. The error message shows you that you are not including `company_id` in the keyword arguments.

Comment: @Alasdair Updated :) - Should the method also include the keyword argument for company? I'd already created a get_absolute_url for the company itself passing in 'company_id'

Comment: The `get_absolute_url` method for the `Company` model and related url pattern have no effect here. You just need to make sure that when you call `reverse`, you include all the args/kwargs for the url pattern you are reversing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your url pattern `people-detail` contains a named group `company_id`, then you must include that when you try to reverse it. For example, if your model has a foreign key to the `Company` model, then you might be able to do:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('people-detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug, 'company_id': self.company_id})
```

Comment: This was perfect - thank you! I had already defined get_absolute_url for the company model so did not realize it was necessary to again pass it the company_id kwarg to this new URL.